psycopg2 having double quotes around placeholder
Postgres CLI:
Using single quotes around username I get an error:
some_db=> CREATE USER 'foobar' WITH PASSWORD 'pass';
                      ^      ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'foobar'"
LINE 1: CREATE USER 'foobar' WITH PASSWORD 'pass';

But double quotes are fine:
some_db=> CREATE USER "foobar" WITH PASSWORD 'pass';
                      ^      ^
CREATE ROLE

Python code:
When executing this code piece:
db_connection.cursor().execute(
  "CREATE USER %s WITH PASSWORD %s",
  (username, password,)
)

I also get an error:
Error creating User: syntax error at or near "'foobar'"
LINE 1: CREATE USER 'foobar' WITH PASSWORD '9f...

Which is expected as single quotes are added automatically when query parameters are used.
Question: is there a way to configure psycopg2 to use double quotes instead or I need to embed username variable directly in query? Or may be there's another solution? If the second case is the way to go, I need to escape it too. What do you think?

From the psycopg2 module sql:
import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import sql
con = psycopg2.connect("dbname=test user=postgres port=5432")
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute(sql.SQL("create user {} with password %s").format(sql.Identifier('test_usr')), ['test'])
con.commit()
cur.execute("select usename from pg_user where usename = 'test_usr'")
cur.fetchone()
('test_usr',)

This is the safe way for building dynamic SQL.
UPDATE
Clarification of what is going on:
user_sql = sql.SQL("create user {} with password %s").format(sql.Identifier('test_usr'))

print(user_sql.as_string(con))
create user "test_usr" with password %s

The sql module builds a SQL string where the component parts are properly escaped to make them safe. Caveat, it is possible to do unsafe things using sql.SQL when not properly formatting the variable bits:

class psycopg2.sql.SQL(string)


A Composable representing a snippet of SQL statement.


SQL exposes join() and format() methods useful to create a template where to merge variable parts of a query (for instance field or table names).


The string doesn’t undergo any form of escaping, so it is not suitable to represent variable identifiers or values: you should only use it to pass constant strings representing templates or snippets of SQL statements; use other objects such as Identifier or Literal to represent variable parts.

Be sure and read this sql to make sure you are doing the correct thing.

Thanks for your help!
Could you tell me why doesn't it throw a syntax error like my example does? Don't you need to sanitize username?

No, it is handled for you by sql.Identifier. I would read through this sql a couple of times to understand what the module provides.

Add UPDATE to clarify things.
